# Permutations without repetition C

Tags: c, permutation, repeat

I have this code for permutation WITH repetition. Would anyone help to modify it to be WITHOUT repetition. I can't figure it out.

```
int array1[] = {1, 2, 3}; //array can be {1,1,2,3} for example also
int array2[3];

void permWithRep (int array1[], int array2[], int last, int index){
int i, len = last+1;

    enter code here
    for ( i=0; i<len; i++ )
    {
        array2[index] = array1[i] ;

        if (index == last){
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                printf("%d ", array2[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        else // Recur for higher indexes
            permWithRep (array1, array2, last, index+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int len = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int);
    permWithRep (array1, array2, len-1, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you define what you mean by "repetition"?  That may sound like a strange question, but I do not see any repeated code.  Perhaps you are talking about the loops.  Do you want to remove all loops?  Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: For anyone unclear on the terminology of the question - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this on few inputs and it works. 
There is certainly a better way to do it, but that's what i did:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int array1[] = {1, 2, 3}; //array can be {1,1,2,3} for example also
int array2[3]; 
int fixed[3];



void permWithRep(int array1[], int array2[],int fixed_index[], int size , int level){

    if(level == size) return print_array(array2,size);

    for(int k = 0; k< size; k++){

        if(!is_present_in_fixed(fixed_index,level,k)){
            fixed_index[level] = k;
            array2[level] = array1[k];
            permWithRep(array1,array2,fixed_index,size,level+1);
        }

    }
}

void print_array(int array[], int size){
    for(int k = 0; k < size; k++)printf("%d ",array[k]);
    printf("\n");
}

int is_present_in_fixed(int array[], int size, int element ){
    for(int k =0; k<size;k++)
        if(element == array[k]) return 1;
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    int len = sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int);
    permWithRep (array1, array2, fixed, len, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

What I did:

- Add an array (`fixed_index[]`) that keep track of the already *visited* indexes for one permutation.
- In the loop, check if the index of current element belongs to the index already *visited* in that permutation (`is_present_in_fixed(fixed_index,level,k)`).
- If so, it just skip that element (it does not enter the `if` statement).
- Otherwise adds that element to the *visited* for that permutation and go on with recursive call.
- When all array has been iterated on (`level == size`), just print the results contained in `array2`.